# How close do partitions get to perfect squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

This comes purely out of curiosity and experiments. I'm not sure if the literature has any coverage.

Let $p(n)$ be the number of integer partitions of $n$. Then, we have the well-known generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p(n)x^n=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{1-x^k}.$$

> **Question.** For each fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$, is the following set finite?
>   $$\mathcal{A}_k:=\{(n,m)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}^2: p(n)+k=m^2\}.$$

**Update.** Is it even known that $p(n)$ is ever a perfect square beside $n=0, 1$?

Comment: What if $k=0$? Is the answer clear in this case?

Comment: Is $p(n)$ ever a square, for $n\ge2$?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's unclear to me if such is known.

Comment: $p(n)$ is the sequence of coefficients of a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight $-1/2$. If you consider instead the question for the sequence of coefficients of a holomorphic modular form of integral weight say $\geq 4$, you get another question of which I don't know what to expect.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Probably $p(n)$ can't be any perfect power.

Comment: @Alexey, except, of course, $p(1)=1$. But nothing along these lines has been proved, has it?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, it is only a numerical experiment for $p(n)$ with $n\le 10\,000$

Answer (score 4):

Numerical results give random picture. If it is really the case then usual heuristic arguments confirm your conjecture.

ListPlot[Table[FractionalPart[Sqrt[PartitionsP[i]]], {i, 1, 5000}]]

[image]

Distance $0$ number is 1: $p(1)=1^2$. Distance 1 numbers:
\begin{gather}p(2)=1^2+1,\quad p(3)=2^2-1,\quad p(4)=2^2+1,\\p(7)=4^2-1,\quad p(13)=10^2+1,\quad p(35)=122^2-1.\end{gather}
Distance 2 numbers:
$$p(5)=3^2-2,\quad p(6)=3^2+2,\quad p(20)=25^2+2.$$

Comment: Is it clear that these are the only ones?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I've checked $p(n)$ for $n\le 10\,000$. So it is only a reasonable conjecture.